# how to receive POST data sending from another page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem that I got stuck how to receive POST data in angularjs sending from PHP? Let me explain in detail. My project url is `http://test.com/callback` and other party will use `FORM POST` to my `callback` URL. I want to display all `FORM POST` data inside that `callback` controller. Please let me know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Callback url is the server side rest api endpoint right?

Comment: yap, but I want to add that in angularjs

Comment: Do you mean you want to use your **web page** as a **web server** to **receive** POSTS from another page? Well, you POST **to** your **web server**, but you need a **PUSH server** to **forward** data from there to your `http://test.com/callback`, or refresh your page, or Ajax **from** your page to ask for data **to** your web server ... Maybe rethink the whole HTTP requests thing?

Comment: I suppose the asker deserves to know how to find out how he can if he can, same as why he can not when he can not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question you must understand these two concepts:

**Web server**: (PHP, Node, Apache, etc): the server **hosting** your page

- receives [HTTP requests](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_transferencia_de_hipertexto)
- sends HTTP responses

**Web agent**: (Chrome, IE, FF, curl, etc) displaying/**requesting** your page

- sends HTTP requests
- receives HTTP responses

And find out things does not work the way you want.